# elm make from IntelliJ IDEA plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, elm

I'm learning Elm, and I installed the Elm plugin: https://github.com/klazuka/intellij-elm

Fired up IntelliJ IDEA and opened the local copy of this code:

https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-0.19-workshop/tree/master/intro/part1

I understand that I can compile the Main with `elm make Main.elm --output elm.js` from the terminal but I want to know if there's a GUI-way to do this, well, since I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

[File Watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html) are suitable for automatically triggering the `elm make` process.

The [External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-third-party-tools.html) settings are more appropriate for triggering `elm make` from within IntelliJ only when required. Each External Tool can have its own keyboard shortcut defined.

---

An example File Watcher:
[image: An example of a File Watcher running Elm Make]

An example of a configured External Tool:
[image: An example of elm make configured as an External Tool]